# How to access global variable bean:size in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, struts-1

> **Summary**

I have an `ActionForm` which contains a `List<CouvertureAdditionnelle>` that I display through a `logic:iterate` in my `JSP`.

To dynamically add a new `CouvertureAdditionnelle` in this list, I used the `LazyList` decorator with an indexed getter for my collection.

However, I can't figure out how to make my `ActionForm.List<CouvertureAdditionnelle>` aware of this new item added.

In this post: [`dynamic form elements using struts`](https://coderanch.com/t/54199/framework/dynamic-form-elements-struts), it is said that I can access the size of my list and then create HTML elements using the same logic as my iterator and manually create my HTML elements using this size global variable such as:

```
<bean:size name="couverturesAdditionnellesViewModel" property="couverturesAdditionnelle" id="sizeOfCouverturesAdditionnelle" />
```

Great! I now know that I only have to create HTML elements following the same logic as my iterator with the same ids, etc. and Struts shall automatically create the new items in the ActionForm list automatically!

> **Question**

But how can I now access this global variable in javascript?

> **Code Sample**

**CouverturesAdditionnellesViewModel**

```
public class CouverturesAdditionnellesViewModel extends ActionForm implements Factory {
    public CouverturesAdditionnellesViewModel() {
        couverturesAdditionnelles = LazyList.decorator(new ArrayList<CouvertureAdditionnelle>(), this);
    }

    public List<CouvertureAdditionnelle> getCouverturesAdditionnelles() {
        return couverturesAdditionnelles;
    }

    public CouvertureAdditionnelle getCouverturesAdditionnelles(int index) {
        return couverturesAdditionnelles.get(index);
    }

    public void setCouverturesAdditionnelles(final List<CouverturesAdditionnelles> list) {
        couverturesAdditionnelles = list;
    }

    public void setCouverturesAdditionnelles(int index, CouvertureAdditionnelle item) {
        couverturesAdditionnelles.add(index, item);
    }

    @Override
    public Object create() { return new CouvertureAdditionnelle(); }

    protected List<CouvertureAdditionnelle> couverturesAdditionnelles;
}
```

**struts-config.xml**

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="couverturesAdditionnellesViewModel" type="com.wmi.project.viewModels.couverturesAdditionnelles.CouverturesAdditionnellesViewModel" />
<form-beans>
```

**JSP**

```
<c:set id="index" value="0" />
<logic:iterate name="couverturesAdditionnellesViewModel" 
               property="couverturesAdditionnelles"
               id="couverturesAdditionnelles">
    <html:text name="couverturesAdditionnelles"
               property="codeClassification"
               indexed="true"
               styleId="codeClassification${index}"
               styleClass="form-control search" />
    <!-- etc. etc. -->
</logic:iterate>
<bean:size name="couverturesAdditionnellesViewModel"
           property="couverturesAdditionnelles"
           id="sizeOfCouverturesAdditionnelles" />
...
<script>
    // HOW TO ACCESS sizeOfCouverturesAdditionnelles HERE PLZ?
    var g_sizeOfCouverturesAdditionnelles = HELP!!! =P

    function addNewCouvertureAdditionnelle() {
        // Generate HTML elements' id based on g_sizeOfCouverturesAdditionnelles, etc.
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You use a bean tag in the JS code template and make sure it's properly JS-escaped.

Comment: Thanks, would you provide an example for the ease of understanding? I understand functionally what you mean, but I don't know how to do it technically. A detailed answer would be appreciated. :)

Comment: `var whatever = <bean:whatever />` but with quotes if it's a string, and JS-escaped (almost certainly). There's no real reason to do that in the JSP, set it in the action and expose it directly.

Comment: `<bean:size id="myCollectionSize" name="myActionForm" property="myActionFormCollectionProperty" />`, this is an article I read about adding a new object in a list using a LazyList within your ActionForm, and simply add HTML elements te represent the entity in the same fashion the `<logic:iterator>` or `<c:forEach>` does, and that's it! No need to project a certain amount of entities on load, they're added dynamically. But for this, one needs to get a hook on the collection size in order to index properly. That's what I wanna come up with. And I expect the size to be an integer. Plz post answer

Comment: If elements are added dynamically then you'll need to use that variable from JS as well, which apparently you're doing. If it's an integer then what I posted above should work as long as the JS is in a file processed on the server side (e.g., JSP)